# In bash how can you create an alias to cd then do grunt serve?

Tags: alias, bash

This seems so simple, but I cannot find the answer.  What I am trying to do is...

```
alias projTY run='cd proj/pname/ grunt serve'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding semicolon like:

```
alias projTY="cd proj/pname/; grunt serve"
```

Comment: Can you paste the command that you executed and output of the same?

Comment: I ran projTY and it takes me to the project, but it does do the grunt serve.

Comment: Nevermind... the issue was in the real code I was doing proj run for my alias.  I also had proj as an alias.  Therefore run didn't happen.  Thanks for the help.